# The remote server returned an error (404) Not Found - VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-7.5, vs-web-site-project

I have recently converted a Visual Studio 2013 solution file to use Visual Studio 2015.  The solution file contains an old web site project.  I was able to configure the solution and all projects without any issues.  The problem is when I try to debug the web site project, I get the following error:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server.  The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

In the Property Pages module -> Start Options, I selected "Use custom server" and put in the virtual directory I created in the IIS.

When I open the solution file (.sln) in NotePad, it looks like the project setting were not overwritten by the changes I made in the Property Pages.  It still has some of the IIS Express options:

```
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "MyWebSite", "http://localhost:49706", "{9A8F5D0D-F224-4EAB-B3E0-0097506740F6}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        SccProjectName = "SAK"
        SccAuxPath = "SAK"
        SccLocalPath = "SAK"
        SccProvider = "SAK"
        UseIISExpress = "true"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5"
        ProjectReferences = "{888a9b0e-6570-45ce-969c-c80c1830aea7}|Business.dll;{BF31B05E-A971-419E-865A-B3BBEF8847AC}|Data.dll;{F23338D5-DD16-4BB5-B7C8-FC453CD42CEB}|Sys.dll;"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_49706"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "MyWebSite\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_49706\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_49706"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "MyWebSite\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_49706\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        SlnRelativePath = "MyWebSite\"
    EndProjectSection
    ProjectSection(SvnOrigin) = preProject
        @Keys = Enlist,Svn.Uri
        Enlist = Required
        Svn.Uri = MyWebSite/
    EndProjectSection
```

When I changed "http://localhost:49706" to the virtual directory in IIS in NotePad and save the solution file, the project disappears from soluion explorer.  When I right click and try to reload the project, I get the following message:

> Error opening web http://localhost/MyWebSite.  The Web Site 'http://localhost/MyWebSite' is configured to use IIS Express as the web server but the URL is currently configured on the local IIS web server.  To open this Web Site, you must use IIS Manager to remove the bindings using the URL from the local IIS web server.

What can I do to resolve this error to debug the project in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Did you solve this?